# Sistema de abas JQuery JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Tenho um sistema com abas em **JS/JQuery**, que ao unílo com o ***Owl.Carousel*** ele da um bug um tanto quanto estranho, ja tentei de tudo para consertar o erro e não compreendo oque pode estar causando o conflito.

- **Ex escrito:** Quando carrego a página, e mudo a aba pela primeira vez, as imagens são alinhadas em fileiras ignorando o ***Overflow*** do elemento, ao voltar para outra aba e depois retornar, o ***overflow*** é corrigido, porém sempre que carrego a página o mesmo erro ocorre.
- **Ex imagem:**
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- **Código:**

```js
//Função 'Ocultar/Exibir' Abas.
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.conteudo').hide();
       $('.conteudo:eq(0)').show();
   $('.item_aba:eq(0)').addClass('ativo');
   $('.item_aba').click(function(){
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('.item_aba').removeClass('ativo');
    $(this).addClass('ativo');
    $('.conteudo').hide();
    $('.conteudo:eq('+i+')').show();
   });
})

//Função Owl.Carousel.
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   margin:10,
   loop:false,
   dots:false,
   autoWidth:true,
   items:4
  })
});

//Função Barra Rolante.
var SETTINGS = {
navBarTravelling: false,
navBarTravelDirection: "",
 navBarTravelDistance: 150
}

var colours = {
0: "#00BFFF",
1: "#32CD32",
2: "#FF0000",
3: "#40FEFF",
4: "#14CC99",
5: "#00BAFF",
6: "#0082B2",
7: "#B25D7A",
8: "#00FF17",
9: "#006B49",
10: "#00B27A",
11: "#996B3D",
12: "#CC7014",
13: "#40FF8C",
14: "#FF3400",
15: "#ECBB5E",
16: "#ECBB0C",
17: "#B9D912",
18: "#253A93",
19: "#125FB9",
}


document.documentElement.classList.remove("no-js");
document.documentElement.classList.add("js");

// the indicator
var indicador = document.getElementById("indicador");
var trilho = document.getElementById("trilho");

// Set the indicator
moveIndicator(trilho.querySelector("[aria-selected=\"true\"]"), colours[0]);


// Handle setting the currently active link
trilhoContents.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".trilho_classe_Link"));
links.forEach(function(item) {
 item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
})
e.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
// Pass the clicked item and it's colour to the move indicator function
moveIndicator(e.target, colours[links.indexOf(e.target)]);
});


// var count = 0;
function moveIndicator(item, color) {
var textPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect();
var container = trilhoContents.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var distance = textPosition.left - container;
 var scroll = trilhoContents.scrollLeft;
indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + (distance + scroll) + "px) scaleX(" + textPosition.width * 0.01 + ")";
// count = count += 100;
// indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + count + "px)";

if (color) {
    indicador.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
}

function determineOverflow(content, container) {
var containerMetrics = container.getBoundingClientRect();
var containerMetricsRight = Math.floor(containerMetrics.right);
var containerMetricsLeft = Math.floor(containerMetrics.left);
var contentMetrics = content.getBoundingClientRect();
var contentMetricsRight = Math.floor(contentMetrics.right);
var contentMetricsLeft = Math.floor(contentMetrics.left);
 if (containerMetricsLeft > contentMetricsLeft && containerMetricsRight < contentMetricsRight) {
    return "both";
} else if (contentMetricsLeft < containerMetricsLeft) {
    return "left";
} else if (contentMetricsRight > containerMetricsRight) {
    return "right";
} else {
    return "none";
}
}
```

```css
/*==================== STYLE BARRA ROLANTE ======================*/
 
 * {
  box-sizing: inherit;
 }

 .menu_horizontal {
  position: relative;
  /*padding: 0 11px;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
  .trilho_classe {
  /* Make this scrollable when needed */
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
  .js & {
   /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
   -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
   /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
   &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
   }
  }
  /* positioning context for advancers */
  position: relative;
  /*Crush the whitespace here*/
  font-size: 0;
 }

 .trilho_classe_Contents {
  float: left;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
 }

 .trilho_classe_Contents-no-transition {
  transition: none;
 }

 .trilho_classe_Link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #888;
  /*Reset the font size*/
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 44px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0 11px;
  & + & {
   border-left-color: #eee;
  }
  &[aria-selected="true"] {
   color: #111;
  }
 }

 .trilho_classe_Indicator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
 }
 
 /*==================== FIM STYLE BARRA ROLANTE ======================*/
 
 /*==================== STYLE CONTEÚDO ======================*/
 
 #corpo{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
 }
  .conteudocaixas{
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .imagemcaixas{
   margin-top: 5px;
   width: 12.15%;
   max-width: 170px;
   height: auto;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .position_btcx{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 6px 10px 0 0;
      float: right;
  }
  .button_cx{
   background: #fff;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
 
  .conteudo {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   background: #D1D1D1;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .conteudo p {
   margin: 20px;
  }
 
  /*==================== FIM STYLE CONTEÚDO ======================*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div id="corpo">
  
   <div class="menu_horizontal">
    <nav id="trilho" class="trilho_classe">

     

     <div id="trilhoContents" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
      
      <div class="item_aba trilho_classe_Link" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" aria-selected="true">Menu 1</div>
      <div class="item_aba trilho_classe_Link" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" aria-selected="false">Menu 2</div>
      <div class="item_aba trilho_classe_Link" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" aria-selected="false">Menu 3</div>
      
      <span id="indicador" class="trilho_classe_Indicator" style="transform: translateX(0px) scaleX(0.965781); background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);"></span>
     </div>

     <div class="position_btcx" id="navContainer">
      <button class="button_cx" type="button">&lt;</button>
      <button class="button_cx" type="button">&gt;</button>
     </div>
     
    </nav>
   </div>
  
  <div class="conteudo">
   <div class="conteudocaixas owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="conteudo">
   <div class="conteudocaixas owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="conteudo">
   <div class="conteudocaixas owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: Código cheio de erros. Por exemplo, o que é `trilhoContents2`? Essa variável aparece perdida sem nenhuma declaração.

Comment: é uma duplicação para uma segunda galeria que no caso carrega a classe trilhoContents2, eu tentei simplificar o código retirando a segunda galeria para não ficar cheio de informação e acabei esquecendo alguns trechos como uma classe CSS e JavaScript.

Comment: Editado, removi os códigos da duplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa desse `$('.conteudo').hide();`, basta colocar no CSS `display: none;`.

Também não precisa dois `$(document).ready(function(){`, pode colocar tudo num só.

Defina a classe `.owl-stage` para ter no mínimo 100%:

```
.owl-stage{
   min-width: 100%;
}
```

Também não precisa da propriedade `white-space: nowrap;`, porque não faz efeito.

Use o callback `onInitialized` para definir a altura de todas as caixas com a mesma altura da primeira:

```
onInitialized: function(){
   $('.conteudocaixas').css('height', $('.conteudocaixas:eq(0)').outerHeight()+'px');
}
```

Veja:

```js
//Função Owl.Carousel.
$(document).ready(function(){

//Função 'Ocultar/Exibir' Abas.
//   $('.conteudo').hide();
         $('.conteudo:eq(0)').show();
   $('.item_aba:eq(0)').addClass('ativo');
   $('.item_aba').click(function(){
            $('.conteudo').css('height', '0');
    var i = $(this).index();
    $('.item_aba').removeClass('ativo');
    $(this).addClass('ativo');
    $('.conteudo').hide();
    $('.conteudo:eq('+i+')').show();
   });

  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   margin:10,
   loop:false,
   dots:false,
   autoWidth:true,
   items:4,
         onInitialized: function(){
            $('.conteudocaixas').css('height', $('.conteudocaixas:eq(0)').outerHeight()+'px');
         }
  })
});

//Função Barra Rolante.
var SETTINGS = {
navBarTravelling: false,
navBarTravelDirection: "",
 navBarTravelDistance: 150
}

var colours = {
0: "#00BFFF",
1: "#32CD32",
2: "#FF0000",
3: "#40FEFF",
4: "#14CC99",
5: "#00BAFF",
6: "#0082B2",
7: "#B25D7A",
8: "#00FF17",
9: "#006B49",
10: "#00B27A",
11: "#996B3D",
12: "#CC7014",
13: "#40FF8C",
14: "#FF3400",
15: "#ECBB5E",
16: "#ECBB0C",
17: "#B9D912",
18: "#253A93",
19: "#125FB9",
}


document.documentElement.classList.remove("no-js");
document.documentElement.classList.add("js");

// the indicator
var indicador = document.getElementById("indicador");
var trilho = document.getElementById("trilho");

// Set the indicator
moveIndicator(trilho.querySelector("[aria-selected=\"true\"]"), colours[0]);


// Handle setting the currently active link
trilhoContents.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".trilho_classe_Link"));
links.forEach(function(item) {
 item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
})
e.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
// Pass the clicked item and it's colour to the move indicator function
moveIndicator(e.target, colours[links.indexOf(e.target)]);
});


// var count = 0;
function moveIndicator(item, color) {
var textPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect();
var container = trilhoContents.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var distance = textPosition.left - container;
 var scroll = trilhoContents.scrollLeft;
indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + (distance + scroll) + "px) scaleX(" + textPosition.width * 0.01 + ")";
// count = count += 100;
// indicador.style.transform = "translateX(" + count + "px)";

if (color) {
    indicador.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
}

function determineOverflow(content, container) {
var containerMetrics = container.getBoundingClientRect();
var containerMetricsRight = Math.floor(containerMetrics.right);
var containerMetricsLeft = Math.floor(containerMetrics.left);
var contentMetrics = content.getBoundingClientRect();
var contentMetricsRight = Math.floor(contentMetrics.right);
var contentMetricsLeft = Math.floor(contentMetrics.left);
 if (containerMetricsLeft > contentMetricsLeft && containerMetricsRight < contentMetricsRight) {
    return "both";
} else if (contentMetricsLeft < containerMetricsLeft) {
    return "left";
} else if (contentMetricsRight > containerMetricsRight) {
    return "right";
} else {
    return "none";
}
}
```

```css
/*==================== STYLE BARRA ROLANTE ======================*/
 
 * {
  box-sizing: inherit;
 }

 .menu_horizontal {
  position: relative;
  /*padding: 0 11px;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
  .trilho_classe {
  /* Make this scrollable when needed */
  overflow-x: auto;
  /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
  .js & {
   /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
   -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
   /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
   &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
   }
  }
  /* positioning context for advancers */
  position: relative;
  /*Crush the whitespace here*/
  font-size: 0;
 }

 .trilho_classe_Contents {
  float: left;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
 }

 .trilho_classe_Contents-no-transition {
  transition: none;
 }

 .trilho_classe_Link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #888;
  /*Reset the font size*/
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 44px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0 11px;
  & + & {
   border-left-color: #eee;
  }
  &[aria-selected="true"] {
   color: #111;
  }
 }

 .trilho_classe_Indicator {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
 }
 
 /*==================== FIM STYLE BARRA ROLANTE ======================*/
 
 /*==================== STYLE CONTEÚDO ======================*/
 
 #corpo{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  
 }
   
.owl-stage{
   min-width: 100%;
}

  .conteudocaixas{
   overflow-x: scroll;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   /* white-space: nowrap; */
  }
  .imagemcaixas{
   margin-top: 5px;
   width: 12.15%;
   max-width: 170px;
   height: auto;
   display: inline-block;
  }
  .position_btcx{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 6px 10px 0 0;
      float: right;
  }
  .button_cx{
   background: #fff;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
  }
  
 
  .conteudo {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
   background: #D1D1D1;
   margin: 0 auto;
         display: none;
  }
  .conteudo p {
   margin: 20px;
  }
 
  /*==================== FIM STYLE CONTEÚDO ======================*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div id="corpo">
  
   <div class="menu_horizontal">
    <nav id="trilho" class="trilho_classe">

     

     <div id="trilhoContents" class="trilho_classe_Contents">
      
      <div class="item_aba trilho_classe_Link" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" aria-selected="true">Menu 1</div>
      <div class="item_aba trilho_classe_Link" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" aria-selected="false">Menu 2</div>
      <div class="item_aba trilho_classe_Link" style="cursor: hand;" href="#" aria-selected="false">Menu 3</div>
      
      <span id="indicador" class="trilho_classe_Indicator" style="transform: translateX(0px) scaleX(0.965781); background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);"></span>
     </div>

     <div class="position_btcx" id="navContainer">
      <button class="button_cx" type="button">&lt;</button>
      <button class="button_cx" type="button">&gt;</button>
     </div>
     
    </nav>
   </div>
  
  <div class="conteudo">
   <div class="conteudocaixas owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver10_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="conteudo">
   <div class="conteudocaixas owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver11_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="conteudo">
   <div class="conteudocaixas owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imagemcaixas" src="http://cdn.cinepop.com.br/2017/06/spiderman_homecoming_ver12_xlg.jpg" alt="#"/></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
```